# How to create a catalog site with views and taxonomy?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks, uri

I'm trying to setup a site where users can download pdfs that are sorted into different categories based what type are. I've coded out what I want in a html version (which is currently live [here](http://www.symbio.com.au/data-sheets/)) but I need to make this into a CMS (first time for me in Drupal, I've been using other CMSs such Wordpress).

Here's the structure I'm after (also would like to have the URL aliases mention below):

Displayed on Main Download Page (url: domainname/downloadpage):

(Probably a block)

- First Top Category

  - First Sub Category
  - Second Sub Category
  - Third Sub Category

(Also a block)

- Second Top Category

  - First Sub Category
  - Second Sub Category
  - Third Sub Category

Displayed on Top Category Page (url: domainname/downloadpage/firsttopcategory):

(A block but doesn't have to be)

- First Top Category

  - First Sub Category
  - Second Sub Category
  - Third Sub Category

Displayed on Sub Category Page [already worked this out- just trying to link/incorporate it] (url: domainname/downloadpage/firsttopcategory/firstsubcategory):

- First Sub Category

    [in a table]
  - Download Name  Field1 Field2  Download Link
  - Name  Field1 Field2  Download Link

I've already worked out how to create a content type for this, all I need to get this structure into place. [This has been a good help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1jqu8JnLbU) but I can't seem to get the way I need it with what I'm after. If you could point me in the right direction in order to archive this, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'll point you in the right direciton. In your view, Under Advanced, RELATIONSHIP click add, and add Taxonomy term.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at either of these modules, both have an official D7 version (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [Taxonomy Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block)

  > Taxonomy Menu Block allows you to make blocks containing unordered lists that represent the structure of your vocabularies, creating a menu out of your taxonomies (without using Drupal's menu system).
  >
  > Taxonomy Menu Block combines the idea of [Taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) with the workings of [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block):
  >
  > - Make multiple menus per vocabulary.
  > - "Split" the taxonomy into different menus.
  >     This allows, for example, the creation of one menu with only the top items (parents) of a vocabulary and another menu with only the sub-items (children).
  > - Make a menu out of a specific branch of your vocabulary only.
  > - Follow the active trail, also for nodes coupled to a term with a term reference field.
  >
  > Taxonomy Menu Block also comes with its own theme function and a few hooks (see the .api.php file) that allows you to alter the generated data to your needs.
- [Taxonomy Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_block)

  > This module displays a list of taxonomy terms in a block from a single vocabulary.